# How to set stop loss at previous low of long entry?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to set a stoploss at previous low of long entry.
which command I need to use ?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9imo.png)

currently I use

```
if ta.change(strategy.position_size) == 0
    strategy.exit(id="Close Long", stop=low)


if ta.change(strategy.position_size) == 0
    strategy.exit(id="Close Short", stop=high)
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect the lowest value of a given number of bars back, you can use :

```
lowest_value = ta.lowest(close,10)
```

It will give you the lowest value available on the 10 bars back.